# Getting message from Error enum without using case statement in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a bunch of errors defined like this:

```
public enum ClientError: Error {
    //...
    case badRequest(message: String)
    case invalidParameter(message: String)
    case notAuthorized(message: String)
    case securityFailed(message: String)
    //...
}
```

Etc. The list is quite lengthy

Some codes are handled in specific way, but for most of them I just want to display a `message`. Currently, however, we are still handling each type of error in `switch`, so we can get a message:

```
switch(error) {
//...
case badRequest(let message):
    displayError(message: message)
case invalidParameter(let message):
    displayError(message: message)
case notAuthorized(let message):
    someSpecialHandling()
case securityFailed(let message):
    displayError(message: message)
//...
}
```

So what I would like instead is to have switch for `someSpecialHandling` only, and have `displayError(message: message)` in `default` case. Problem is: how do I get `message` in such case?
Here's how I would like the code to look like:

```
switch(error) {
//...
case notAuthorized(let message):
    someSpecialHandling()
default:
    displayError(message: message) <-- how to obtain message here?
//...
}
```

Or something like:

```
switch(error) {
//...
case notAuthorized(let message):
    someSpecialHandling()
default:
    break
//...
}

let message = //get message from Error somehow
displayError(message: message)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match values with the same associated value type on the same `case` statement.

```swift
public enum ClientError: Error {
    case badRequest(message: String)
    case invalidParameter(message: String)
    case notAuthorized(message: String)
    case securityFailed(message: String)
    case someOtherError(code: Int)
    case anotherError(code: Int)
    case whatever
}

//[...]

switch error {
case let .badRequest(message),
     let .invalidParameter(message),
     let .notAuthorized(message),
     let .securityFailed(message):
    // Handle the message
case let .someOtherError(code),let .anotherError(code):
   // Handle the code
case. whatever:
   // Do something 
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to retrieve the associated value without listing all the cases.